# Jquery DataTables.net: Failing to put negative int in table

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have an API that returns some negative numbers for the Id field.  Here is my datatables script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myTable').DataTable( {
                ajax: {
                    url: '@Url.Content("~/api/cas/nodes/all/lastcondition/")',
                    "columns": [
                        { "type" : "num", "data": "Id"},
                        { "data": "Name" },
                        { "data": "Alias" },
                        { "data": "DateQuery" },
                        { "type" : "num", "data": "Condition" },
                        { "type" : "num", "data": "TimeSecLastCondition" }
                    ]
                }

            } );
        });
```

JSON returned from ajax query:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "Id": -2144725655,
        "Name": "NodeName",
        "Alias": "NodeAlias",
        "DateQuery": "2015-11-13T08:16:04",
        "Condition": 0,
        "TimeSecLastCondition": 1558
    }]
}
```

Error:

> "Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0."

Comment: works fine here -> http://jsfiddle.net/egpxdsq7/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing the ajax option and other options. Instead of

```
ajax: {
    url: '@Url.Content("~/api/cas/nodes/all/lastcondition/")',
    "columns": [
        { "type" : "num", "data": "Id"},
        { "data": "Name" },
        { "data": "Alias" },
        { "data": "DateQuery" },
        { "type" : "num", "data": "Condition" },
        { "type" : "num", "data": "TimeSecLastCondition" }
    ]
})
```

you should do

```
ajax: {
    url: '@Url.Content("~/api/cas/nodes/all/lastcondition/")'
},
columns: [
     { "type" : "num", "data": "Id"},
     { "data": "Name" },
     { "data": "Alias" },
     { "data": "DateQuery" },
     { "type" : "num", "data": "Condition" },
     { "type" : "num", "data": "TimeSecLastCondition" }
  ]
}
```